# Different sizes after copy

Tags: disk-usage, cp, recursive

I would like to copy for backup porposes a Linux user `home` directory with several GBs of data and the usual configuration files. The source directory and the backup directory should exactly have the **same** contents. The OS is Lubuntu.

The directory contains hidden files and subdirectories. After some googling I found that

```
cp -r /source-directory /backup-directory
```

was the appropriate command.

The source directory filesystem is ext4 and the destination directory is NTFS. After the copy, `diff -qr /source-directory /backup-directory` gives no output (so I suppose no differences). But `du`, or `du -b` or `du --apparent-size` all give always different outputs for the source directory and the backup directory.

Why? Was the command wrong or is this use of `du` wrong?

Comment: You should us '-a' too for archive mode.

Comment: `cp -ar` still gives different outputs with `du`.

Answer (score 4):

Additional blocks are allocated, as needed, to directories as files and sub-directories are added.  Subsequent removal of these files and sub-directories do not result in disposal of the now empty/reusable allocation.  Hence it is very common for the destination directory of a copy operation to be slightly smaller than its source.

You can `diff` recursively the source and destination directories to confirm everything has been copied if you want a warm-fuzzy confirmation.

As an aside, `rsync` is also ideal for replicating structures:

```
rsync -avz /source-directory/ /backup-directory
```

The trailing slash on the source-directory means that the source-directory name is not included in the backup-directory as its first sub-directory.

The `-avz` options tell `rsync` to copy in archive mode to preserve permissions, ownerships, symbolic links, etc., using compresssion during the transfer process and reporting actions verbosely.

Comment: I was recommended this question for `sparse file` or `sparseness` - just adding the keywords for others that will CTR+F this page x)

Answer (score 1):

Different filesystems may have differing overhead while allocating space for files. Also how directory entries are stored may differ. You unfortunately don't tell *what* the different outputs are.