# diff doesn't return anything, but total size is different?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ext4, diff, file-comparison

Usually I like to use a following diff command setup to recursively compare 2 directory structures:

`diff --brief --recursive  dir/one dir/two`

However on my last attempt it **returned nothing**, so I thought, hey that's good, but then I've opened properties of each of those folders:

- same number of files 6496 items
- the sizes were almost the same, but just **almost** 1 has **660,5MB** but the other one has **660,7MB** - 200KB difference

And since this is in a process for data import purposes I need to know:

- How can this happen?
- Does `diff` also compare contents? Or is it optional? (if so, how can one enforce that?) Could not find more info in docs.

**Additional important info:**

- Both folders have the **same data source** but **different tool** was used to extract them
- Both folders have the **same parent directory**
- OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Filesystem where they're stored is Ext4(Version 1.0) on an SSD disk
- GUI tool for folder properties was used Nautilus - Gnome's "Files" version 3.36.3-stable

**EDIT:** During solving this Q I've created a little Python3 script, that just blindly counts all files(not folders) and their total size count in bytes for all directories you will send to it

1. save this code: https://ideone.com/4pu1qs as `quick_dir_compare.py`

2. use as `python3 quick_dir_compare.py dirpath1 dirpath2 .....`

2.x if you don't have python3: `sudo apt install python3` before 2.

license: I grant free for all legal and human-rights purposes

Comment: One or more files may be sparse. How are you measuring the sizes? If you're using `du`, then this will show the actual size on disk, not the logical (apparent) size of the files. Try again with `du --apparent-size` (assuming you have GNU `du`).

Comment: Related, if not dupes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161814/different-sizes-after-copy and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106275/du-gives-two-different-results-for-the-same-file

Comment: @Kusalananda I'd agree with 161814 but I'm not so sure about the other

Comment: The information you supplied is not sufficient to help. I would recommend to use `star -diff` to compare both trees since `star` compares not only file content but also file types, meta data and sparseness. Try e.g. `star -c -dump -diff -v -sparse -C fromdir . todir`.

Comment: @Kusalananda whether your guesses applydepends on what the OP understands by size differs.... If this is related to the `du` output, then the trees indeed may be identical.

Comment: @schily I don't have a `star` command available nor it is listed in the suggested packages - what is its package and is it available for ubuntu?

Comment: @Kusalananda  I've measured the sizes by the Nautilus's "Properties" in the Files GUI as I've mentioned in Additional information :) `du -s dir` on both directories also returns different result `657164` and `657320`

Comment: @jave.web And if you run with `--apparent-size` as I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @Kusalananda 161814 - not related and not a dupe - that's replicating existing folder structure - not this case, 106275 - provides option to display more accurate information `du -s -b dir` returns `660539309` and `660539309` (`-b` is short for `--bytes` "equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1`")

Comment: So, you have one or several sparse file. The question that I linked to, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161814/different-sizes-after-copy explains what have happened. You had a sparse file in the source directory, and after copying it, it is no longer sparse. This is why the target directory is larger when you check with a command that counts actual disk usage.

Comment: Sorry, that question is not about what I thought it was. Sorry. I will update with a better example question.  Here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252627/copied-a-folder-getting-different-used-space-on-destination-using-freebsd-and  (there are likely other better dupes).

Comment: Does directory size (not regular file size) also sometimes give strange results (disk size not apparent-size), that is different depending if you got to where you are by adding or removing files.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes one dir was creating by extracting the source and then deleting files and folder that we don't care about, other was creating by byte-by-byte extracting only files we want - resulting in the same directory and file structure from the same source

Comment: Note if the only difference is in sparseness: disk-usage `ls -ls` vs apparent-size `ls -l`. Then you can ignore it. Disk-usage size only matters if you care about disk-usage.

Comment: So is it the directory size that differs (and not the regular files)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm sorry I thought you meant the question, you meant the ANSWER to that question (you can share direct link to the answer too ;) ) **that actually could explain what is hapenning)**

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor there is like a LOT of files, so I've only checked with `diff` as I mentioned in the question - which does **not** find any differences and then directory contents size - can I somehow count sizes of all files recursively?

Comment: Isn't there a native linux cross-distro or ubuntu way to count all files ?

Comment: So I've written a little python script for it - I've added as an **EDIT** to the Question -   results were the same both 5888 files and both total file size of 657713069 :) (Hurray!)

Comment: Run something like `cd dir/one; find . -type d -ls | sort > /tmp/listing-one.txt`, and the same for the other one, and diff those listings. If you see any differences, it's what @ctrl said, that the sizes of the _directories_ are not the same. That's normal, the space allocated for the directory is extended when more space is needed (more files created), but never reduced or compacted. Similarly, you could run the same with `-type f` instead, to look at the sizes of the files. (Note, you want to `cd` in the dir, and give `find` the path `.`, otherwise the paths are different for _all_ files.)